# CD Doesn't Work? (OS X)

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, macosx, livedvd

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit version, converted it to `.img`, and successfully burned it to a CD. But when I inserted the CD, it said,

```
This disk is not readable by this computer.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Read [How to burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx). Also, remember the ISO does not (officially) fit on a CD, but you must use a DVD (or USB stick) for better results.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Desktop download is and .iso file which can be directly written to a CD or DVD. You should not convert it to a .img before burning it.